# Finding Limit points of Z in R using the given definition

Tags: metric-spaces

I am asked to find the set of limit points of Z in R using the definition given below:
 Let (R,d) be a metric space.
A point x belonging to R is called a limit point of Z if each open sphere centered on x contains atleast one point of Z other than x, in other words, if
(B(x,r)-{x}) intersection with Z is null set.
So if I choose any arbitrary x in R, then how should I show that the set of limit points is null set? Means What should I show using the definition? Does (B(x,r) -{x}) intersection with Z comes to be null set for every x in R?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in definition. It is (B(x,r) -{x}) intersection with Z is not a null set.

Comment: Repair your mistake by means of an edit. In general you should must detect wich for $x\in R$ some $r>0$ exists such that the intersection of $B(x,r)-\{x\}$ with $Z$ is empty. If you can find such $r$ then $x$ is *not* a limitpoint of $Z$. If you cannot then $x$ is a limitpoint of $Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the set of all limit points of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is empty; for, let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the deleted ball $B^{x}(\varepsilon) - \{ x \}$ of center $x$ and radius $\varepsilon$ has no intersection with $\mathbb{Z}$ for all $0 < \varepsilon < 1$; if $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$, let $d := \min \{ x - \lfloor x \rfloor, \lceil x \rceil - x \}$; then $B^{x}(\varepsilon ) - \{ x \}$ again has no intersection with $\mathbb{Z}$ for all $0 < \varepsilon < d$.

Comment: what is your small d in last expression?

Comment: Sorry i found it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am not getting what have you chosen d as . Is it greatest integer function [x] in d= min{ x-[x],[x]-x}?

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer lower bound of $x$; $\lceil x \rceil$ denotes the smallest integer upper bound of $x$.